# How to sort an array of structs that has some NULL values using qsort

Tags: c, sorting, struct, qsort

I have an array of structs that I need to sort based on an attribute. I made a compare function to do that but the problem is that the array can have NULL values and that causes errors. Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
#define MAX_NUM 5
struct d {
    int id;
    int p;
    int prio;
} d;
struct d *P[MAX_NUM];


int compare(const void *p, const void *q)
{
    int l = ((struct d *)p)->prio;
    int r = ((struct d *)q)->prio;
    if (l < r) return -1;
    else if (l > r) return 1;
    else  return 0;

}
```

And I call the qsort function like this:

```
qsort(P, MAX_NUM, sizeof(P[0]), compare);
```

I think this should work in normal circumstances but since array P has NULL values it doesn't. How could I make this work?

Edit: my last modification of compare function based on the comments:

```
int usporedba(const void* a, const void* b) 
{
   struct d arg1 = *(const struct d*)a;
   struct d arg2 = *(const struct d*)b;

   if (arg1.prio < arg2.prio) return -1;
   if (arg1.prio > arg2.prio) return 1;
   return 0;
```

}

Comment: `struct d *P[MAX_NUM];` This is an array of *pointers to* structs, while the question says *array of structs*. `struct dretva` Not defined. `sizeof(d)` That's not the sizeof an element in P. Please post real code.

Comment: My mistake with the question title, I'm not very experienced with C. I've changed some variable names here but I guess I forgot some but it's fixed now. The entire code is somewhat long so I've just posted the important parts, everything else is not relevant to the question.

Comment: Question remains what you want to sort. An array of structs would be `struct d P[MAX_NUM];`. The posted code shows an array of pointers to structs, instead. Either one can be sorted, but the `qsort` calls are different in the two cases. Also, `sizeof(P)` is still wrong in both cases. See the [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort), in particular the `size` argument. And, again, please post the minimal but complete code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @dxiv it needs to stay an array of pointers to structs, what should the qsort call be in that case?

Comment: Take the example at the link in my previous comment and replace `int` with `struct d*`.

Comment: Damn I'm confused now, I tried doing that and it doesn't work I assume I didn't understand correctly what is that you are saying I should do

Comment: It helped if you posted what you tried and what the errors were. For a hint, the `qsort` call should be `qsort(P, MAX_NUM, sizeof(d*), compare);`.

Comment: Make that `sizeof(struct d*)` or `sizeof(P[0])`.

Comment: Yeah did that, now it doesn't cause the error but array is still not sorted.

Comment: The linked example has `int arg1 = *(const int*)a;`. Now replace `int` with `struct d*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compare function will receive pointers to the members of the array.  Since the array contains elements of type `struct d *`, the parameters are of type `struct d **`.

With that in mind, your compare function should look like this:

```
int usporedba(const void* a, const void* b) 
{
   const struct d *arg1 = *(const struct d **)a;
   const struct d *arg2 = *(const struct d **)b;

   if (!arg1 && !arg2) return 0;
   if (!arg1) return 1;
   if (!arg2) return -1;
   if (arg1->prio < arg2->prio) return -1;
   if (arg1->prio > arg2->prio) return 1;
   return 0;
}
```

This ordering assumes that `NULL` element should be at the end of the array.  If you want them at the beginning, then swap the return values of the second and third conditions.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit :** I did not take into account the mistakes in the given code. (I'm specifying becuase comments to the question made me see you are using a pointer to arrays rather than an array)

---

I'm not sure what you want the `qsort` to do with these `NULL` values. Do you want them all at the beginning? At the end? Or do you want `qsort` to ignore them?

I see three possibilities :

1. If all the NULL values are at the end of the array (or if it's relatively easy to place them all at the end of the array), and it is easy to know how many `NULL` values there is, then when calling `qsort` you could substract the amount of `NULL` values to the argument `MAX_NUM`.
2. In your comparison function, check for NULL values :

```
int compare(const void *p, const void *q)
{
    if (!p && !q)
        return 0;
    if (!p)
        return 1; // or -1
    if (!q)
        return -1; // or 1
    ...
}
```

3. **(Not recommended unless other options are impossible)** If there's a value of `prio` that you know will never occur in your case (such as -2^31 which is −2147483648, or 2^31-1 which is 2147483647), then you can replace all `NULL` values with a placeholder struct which `prio` is this value, and after `qsort` you can re-replace those placeholder values to `NULL`. (This option sounds less efficient than the others to me)

---

Also, instead of comparing twice and returning a hardcoded -1, 0 or 1, you could simply do :

```
int compare(const void *p, const void *q)
{
    ...
    return l - r;
}
```

Which will automatically return a negative value if `l < r`, a positive value if `l > r` and 0 of `l == r`. It's also much more simple :)

Comment: This is one level of indirection off. It's not working and cannot work this way. The NULL case refers to the pointers pointed to by `p, q`, not to `p` or `q` themselves.

Comment: Indeed, I did not read into the full code given by OP and just focused on resolving the problem. There needs extra adaptation for my method to work with the given code. If anyone would like to help me and edit my answer, feel free.